# sorting distinct attributes in SQL's Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I got some problem in using ms. access

I have 1 table "Movie" with 5 attributes which is "Name", "Movie_Genre", "runtime", "Main_Actor" and "Main_Actress"

I try to make a query with distinct of movie genre along with the average of runtime of each genre

I have more than 4 genres which each genre at least have 2 movies with different runtime

I try to write this query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Movie_Genre, Avg(runtime)
 FROM Movie;
```

but I got error message

anyone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  In the future, add any error message you get to the body of your question.  Also, remember to "accept" the best answer you receive that correctly answers your question.

Comment: @Newbie Newbae please note to post your error with your question next time. Errors give more information to find solutions than to bug you :) Keep Stackflowing :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Movie_Genre, 
    Avg(runtime)
FROM 
    Movie
GROUP BY
    Movie_Genre
```

Comment: Great! Here you can read more about GROUP BY : http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/group-by-clause-HA001231482.aspx .